# Async function assign value to a CONST not log to the console

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am trying to create a reusable function to return data from fetch. Like so many others I am only getting the `Promise {<pending>}` not the actual object that is inside the pending promise.

This is my code:

```
async function getapi(u, h, p) {
    const response = await fetch(u,{"method": "POST", headers: h, "body": JSON.stringify(p)});
    var data = await response.json();
    if (response){
        return data
    }
}

const status = getapi(api_url, headers, post);
console.log(status);
```

This will return `Promise {<pending>}`.

However, if I add a function inside the getApi() it will return the actual result like this:

```
async function getapi(u, h, p) {
    const response = await fetch(u,{"method": "POST", headers: h, "body": JSON.stringify(p)});
    var data = await response.json();
    if (response){
        showData(data)
    }
}
const status = getapi(api_url, headers, post);
console.log(status);

function showData(data){
    console.log('showData', data)
}
```

Then the console.log is `{status: 1, result: 1}` however this does not create a reusable wrapper.

I need to get the object returned from the single getapi() function.

Thanks

Comment: `getapi` is an async function, so it returns a promise. Do `const status = await getapi(....`

Comment: `Like so many others` and did you read what so many others found out? ... `async` functions always return a `Promise` by their very nature. You can't use `async` to get asynchronous data synchronously. In fact, you can't use anything at all to do that, since asynchrony can not be tamed -

Comment: Andrew - "Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules"

Comment: @Davidicusrex as the message says, you need to use `await` in an async function or at the top level in a module. If you prefer, you can use `.then()` but it's ultimately the same thing. `await` and `.then()`  are the ways to access the value of a promise. The duplicates cover this thoroughly.

Comment: @vlaz Yes, I understand that.  However every answer is sending the result of the .then()  to a console.log and I am asking how it can assign the result of .then() to a const, not the console.  Can .then() return something?

Comment: No, it cannot. But you can put the entire code using the `const` in there. Or call a function and pass the data as parameter. Or whatever. You're currently asking to *synchronously* access *asynchronous data*. Which isn't possible. The only possible ways are to do it asynchronously. There are no other answers.

Answer (score 0):

`async-await` returns a promise. So you can use the `then` when calling `getapi`

```
async function getapi(u, h, p) {
  const response = await fetch(u, {
    "method": "POST",
    headers: h,
    "body": JSON.stringify(p)
  }).then(resp => resp.json());
  return response;
}

getapi(api_url, headers, post).then(status => console.log(status));
```

Comment: Why change `await` to `.then()`?

Comment: This result is still being logged to the console.  My question was how to have the result assigned to a CONST.